# Declaring self-referencing variable when converting script to V4 breaks charting

Tags: pine-script

I am combining a number of script into a single indicator to create alerts, and am using scripts of different versions, so I am trying to use version 4 for everything.

One of the indicators I am using is the VWAP Standard Deviation bands indicator, which initializes the variables as such:

```
start = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time)

newSession = iff(change(start), 1, 0)


vwapsum = 0.0
volumesum = 0.0
v2sum = 0.0
vwapsum := iff(newSession, hl2*volume, hl2*volume + vwapsum[1])
volumesum := iff(newSession, volume, volume + volumesum[1])
v2sum := iff(newSession, volume*hl2*hl2, volume*hl2*hl2 + v2sum[1])
```

I added the `vwapsum = 0.0` and other initialization because it throws an error otherwise. This is supposed to add values starting at the beginning of the day, so the bands gradually expand and contract at the beginning of the next session. However, I am getting a contraction at the time that I apply the indicator when the market is open.

[image: In this image you can see the contractions. 1. Correct contraction at the beginning of the daily session. 2. Incorrect contraction at the time of opening the chart or applying the indicator.]
In this image you can see the contractions. 1. Correct contraction at the beginning of the daily session. 2. Incorrect contraction at the time of opening the chart or applying the indicator.

What is the correct way to do this to have it chart properly? Is this due to the manual setting of the variables to 0.0, or due to a change in how V4 interprets the newSession statement?

The following is the minimal viable script that reproduces the error:

```
//@version=4

study("VWAP-deviation", overlay=true)

devUp1 = input(title="Stdev above", type=input.float, defval=2.0)
devDn1 = input(title="Stdev below", type=input.float, defval=2.0 )

start = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time)
newSession = iff(change(start), 1, 0)

vwapsum = 0.0
volumesum = 0.0
v2sum = 0.0
vwapsum := iff(newSession, hl2*volume, hl2*volume + vwapsum[1])
volumesum := iff(newSession, volume, volume + volumesum[1])
v2sum := iff(newSession, volume*hl2*hl2, volume*hl2*hl2 + v2sum[1])

myvwap = vwapsum/volumesum
dev = sqrt(max(v2sum/volumesum - myvwap*myvwap, 0))

plot(myvwap, title="VWAP", color=color.green)
plot(myvwap + devUp1 * dev, title="VWAP Upper", color=color.red)
plot(myvwap - devDn1 * dev, title="VWAP Lower", color=color.red)
```

Comment: Please share the entire script instead of just a snippet, so that the community can reproduce your chart.

Comment: As requested I've edited my post to include the script.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this?

```
//@version=4
study("VWAP-deviation", overlay=true)

devUp1 = input(title="Stdev above", type=input.float, defval=2.0)
devDn1 = input(title="Stdev below", type=input.float, defval=2.0 )

var float   vwapsum     = na
var float   volumesum   = na
var float   v2sum       = na

newSession = change(time('D'))

vwapsum     := newSession ? hl2*volume          : hl2*volume            + vwapsum[1]
volumesum   := newSession ? volume              : volume                + volumesum[1]
v2sum       := newSession ? volume * pow(hl2,2) : volume * pow(hl2,2)   + v2sum[1]

myvwap      = vwapsum/volumesum
dev         = sqrt(max(v2sum/volumesum - pow(myvwap,2), 0))

plot(newSession ? na : myvwap               , title="VWAP",       color=color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(newSession ? na : myvwap + devUp1 * dev, title="VWAP Upper", color=color.red,   style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(newSession ? na : myvwap - devDn1 * dev, title="VWAP Lower", color=color.red,   style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. It appears it was specifically the `change(time('D'))` that made it work correctly. Thanks so much.

Comment: No, the clue is in the `newSession ? na :` and `style=plot.style_linebr` in the `plot` function. Your `newSession` implementation worked fine. I just rewrote it with less code.

Comment: Interesting, I understand what you're saying but I implemented the changes incrementally and changing the newSession fixed the issue without implementing the other code.