# Trying to convert V2 VWAP Script to V4 issues

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon all,

I am trying to convert the below V2 VWAP script to V4 but can't get my head around the line 9:

```
vwapsum = iff(newSession, hl2*volume, vwapsum[1]+hl2*volume)
```

Full script below

```
//@version=2
study("Monthly VWAP", overlay=true)
showPrevVWAP = input(true, type=bool, title="Show Previous VWAP close")

start = security(tickerid, "M", time)

newSession = iff(change(start), 1, 0)

vwapsum = iff(newSession, hl2*volume, vwapsum[1]+hl2*volume)
volumesum = iff(newSession, volume, volumesum[1]+volume)

myvwap = vwapsum/volumesum

plot(myvwap, title="VWAP", color=aqua, style=cross)
```

My attempt so far:

```
//@version=4
study("Monthly VWAP", overlay=true)
showPrevVWAP = input(true, type=input.bool, title="Show Previous VWAP close")

start = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", time)

newSession = iff(change(start), 1, 0)

vwapsum = iff(newSession, hl2*volume, vwapsum[1]+hl2*volume)
volumesum = iff(newSession, volume, volumesum[1]+volume)

myvwap = vwapsum/volumesum

plot(myvwap, title="VWAP", color=color.aqua, style=plot.style_cross)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working

```
//@version=4
study("Monthly VWAP", overlay=true)

var float   vwapsum     = na
var float   volumesum   = na

newSession = change(time('M'))

vwapsum     := newSession ? hl2*volume          : hl2*volume            + vwapsum[1]
volumesum   := newSession ? volume              : volume                + volumesum[1]

myvwap      = vwapsum/volumesum

plot(newSession ? na : myvwap               , title="VWAP",       color=color.aqua, style=plot.style_cross)
```

Extracted what I was after from here:
[Declaring self-referencing variable when converting script to V4 breaks charting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634292/declaring-self-referencing-variable-when-converting-script-to-v4-breaks-charting)